# Adding elements of two different sized lists to dictionary with alternating keys?

Tags: python

I am writing code which contains two lists. First list is a list of letters from A-Z. Second list is the list of numbers from 1-100.

The output should be the key value pair of letters and numbers. After getting the key value pair until 26th letter, the alphabet should start from the beginning again with the next consecutive number until 100.

The logic which I wrote is only giving me the result until 26 numbers:

```
import string

alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
number =list(range(1,101))

res = dict(zip(alphabet, number))
print(res)
```

But the output should be in the below format:

```
{
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3,
  'd': 4,
  'e': 5,
  'f': 6,
  'g': 7,
  'h': 8,
  'i': 9,
  'j': 10,
  'k': 11,
  'l': 12,
  'm': 13,
  'n': 14,
  'o': 15,
  'p': 16,
  'q': 17,
  'r': 18,
  's': 19,
  't': 20,
  'u': 21,
  'v': 22,
  'w': 23,
  'x': 24,
  'y': 25,
  'z': 26,
  'a': 27,
  'b': 28,
  'c': 29,
  'd': 30,
  ...
  't': 98, 
  'u': 99,
  'v': 100,
}
```

Comment: All the keys of a dict must be unique, so your desired output can't be produced in Python. You could make a list of 2-tuples instead.

Comment: Or maybe a dictionary where the values are lists. But your expected output can't exist.

Comment: Maybe you want the keys to be the numbers and the values to be the letters?  That would allow you to have 100 elements -- you can have 100 different keys map to some of the same values, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

The comments have already explained that keys in a dictionary are unique, so your desired result is not possible with it. You can instead opt for either one of these solutions:

1. Creating a dictionary with the keys being the letters of the alphabet, and the value a list of indices:

```py
import string

alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

res = {letter: list(range(i, 101, len(alphabet))) for i, letter in enumerate(alphabet, 1)}

print(res)
```

Which outputs `{'a': [1, 27, 53, 79], 'b': [2, 28, 54, 80], ..., 'z': [26, 52, 78]}`.

2. Creating a dictionary where the keys are indices and the value is the corresponding letter:

```py
import string

alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

res = {i: alphabet[(i-1) % len(alphabet)] for i in range(1, 101)}

print(res)
```

Which outputs `{1: 'a', 2: 'b', ..., 100: 'v'}`.

If these aren't useful, I would recommend looking into other data structures. The best approximation would be a list creating tuples of letters and numbers:

```py
import string

alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

res = [(alphabet[(i-1) % len(alphabet)], i) for i in range(1, 101)]

print(res)
```

Which outputs `[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ..., ('v', 100)]`.